# Using Directory.Build.Props to change TargetFrameworkVersion on .NetFramework projects affects .NetStandard projects unexpectedly

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I am trying to change a bunch of projects' TargetFrameworkVersion from v4.6.1 to v4.8 using Directory.Build.props file.
I have a combination of .net framework and .net standard projects beneath Directory.Build.props file, which I want to ignore .net standard ones from updating.
Everything works as expected for .net framework projects But, The condition `"'$(TargetFramework.Contains(netstandard))' == 'false'"`, do the opposite! for .net standard ones.
In other words, the property gets added for this project and Build fails, while it should not.

> MyClassLibrary.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

> Directory.Build.props

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework.Contains(netstandard))' == 'false'">
        <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.8</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

How could it be wrong ?

Comment: You should use `Directory.Build.targets` file rather than `Directory.Build.props` and are you sure it can work with net frameowork project? In my side, it cannot overwrite `net461` to `net48` though it can build net framework projects successfully while it cannot build net standard projects.

Comment: You are absolutely right @PerryQian-MSFT, It also failed for net framework project until I removed that tag from those projects’ .csproj file .

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019#import-order) said, `Directory.Build.props` is imported very early during MSBuild and it means that it will execute the contents of the file first before reading all the properties from `xxx.csproj` file in your project.

And `Directory.Build.targets` is imported at the end of the `xxx.csproj` file, so it can overwrite properties.

`Directory.Build.props` usually is used for creating global properties while `Directory.Build.targets` is used for overwriting properties.

---

For **Net Framework** projects,

**In your issue**, **MSBuild** first reads the property `TargetFrameworkVersion 4.8` in `Directory.Build.props` and it is true.

The property `TargetFramework` does not exist in the `net framework` projects(**it is a property for new sdk project**), so the value is **empty**, and the condition is always `flase` so that the condition is established.(`flase=false`).

**Then**, MSBuild reads the `xxx.csproj`, it will read property `TargetFrameworkVersion 4.6.1` and then overwrite the property `4.8`. So it will always use the value `4.6.1`.

---

For **Net Standard** projects, the property `TargetFramework` is defined under `xxx.csproj` file. And when you first read the content and use it in the `Directory.Build.props` file.

**Because** the file runs before reading `xxx.csproj`, the `TargetFramework` property has not been defined yet, so the condition is `false`. `false=false` leads to the establishment of conditions. It will read the property `TargetFrameworkVersion 4.8` while net standard projects uses property `TargetFramework`.

`TargetFrameworkVersion` is set to `net framework 4.8` while in net standard projects, the value is usually `v2.0` or `v2.1`(`net standard 2.0` or `net standard 2.1`), it cannot read the `net framework 4.8` into a net standard project. And the subsequent `xxx.csproj` file has no value to overwrite `TargetFrameworkVersion` to the normal `net standard` value.

So `TargetFrameworkVersion` is embedded in the `net standard` project as the value of `net framework`, so the build fails due to incompatibility.

**Solution**

**Instead**, you should rename the `Directory.Build.props` file to `Directory.Build.targets`.

**Then**, restart your project, rebuild your solution to enable it. And it can work well in my side.

**Note** that: Although you right click project **Properties**-->**Application**-->**Target Framework** shows the old one `net framework 4.6.1`, the **MSBuild** already set it to `net48`.

[image]

It is just a UI display issue, it doesn't matter, you can ignore it.

Comment: A thorough explanation of what happens under the hood. Thanks a lot @Perry

Comment: Please don't post images of text. You could easily have copy and pasted that console output.